# Getting Error while read Excel data C# window application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net

I am creating a WinForms application using C#.  I'm having an issue reading an Excel spreadsheet.  I am using OleDB API to read it.  My issue is, when the sheet-name in the spreadsheet is less than 31 characters long, it has no problem reading it, but, when the sheet-name is 31 characters long, I am getting an error.  Here is my Excel Query (notice that the sheet-name is "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE" which is 31 characters in length):

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE$A5:T23]
```

When I run that query, I get this error:

> "Microsoft Jet database engine could not found the object ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE$A15:T23.

However, when I change the sheet-name so that it is less than 31 in length, there is no issue.  For instance, this works:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *  FROM [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD$A5:T23]
```

Has anyone else encountered this same issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: the limit on worksheet name is only to 30 characters,. It is hard-coded into Excel at 31 characters.

Comment: @AzeemHafeez its mean Sheet name length must be <31 characters?

Comment: yes it should be